# How do I grep for a backtick?

Tags: bash, find, grep, backticks

So I'm trying to find backticks (`) in files, so I ran:

```
grep -irl '\`' ./*
```

This seems to return every single file possible...

What else can I try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My apologies everyone, you have to use `-I` to ignore binary files. Those were the files that were being returned. I didn't realize this until I removed `-l`, which indicated to me that the results were binary in nature.

```
grep -rlI '`' ./*
```

From the man page:

```
   -I     Process a binary file as if it did not contain  matching  data;
          this is equivalent to the --binary-files=without-match option.
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't actually need to match the backtick itself, but you are looking to match something enclosed by a backtick ( like auto-generated MySQL table names, for instance) a single-character wildcard **(".")** also does the trick.

I'm using it like this today:

```
grep "INSERT INTO .my_table." sqldump.sql
```

Comment: Golden tip; was looking for this exact case.

Answer (score 1):

just go with, it worked for me

```
grep -ri \` *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -irl '`' *
```

or

```
grep -irl \\` *
```